# Setting register values over i2c from Linux (managing power on a PocketCHIP)

Tags: power, i2c, power-management

*TL;DR - I need to set the contents of a register on a power management IC over I2C from Linux running on an SBC. I've found the datasheet for the IC, but I don't know how to use the information in it to formulate the correct `i2cset` command. Skip to the end of this post for the core questions.*

---

I am running a Linux SBC ([Next Thing CHIP](http://www.chip-community.org/index.php/Main_Page)) which uses the [AXP209](http://www.chip-community.org/index.php/Power) IC for power management, balancing between USB, GPIO and battery power as needed. It's part of a handheld ([PocketCHIP](http://www.chip-community.org/index.php/PocketCHIP)) which has a LiPo battery attached.

I've been happily running this daily for a while as an ambient screen, powered from a standalone USB power supply. However, more recently, battery charging has been very noisy and Linux on the unit keeps shutting down with low power warnings, despite being plugged into USB power. This is new behaviour, and the USB power supply hasn't changed.

My working theory is that the battery or the AXP209 is failing, probably the battery.

Ideally, I'd be running the unit with no battery attached at all, entirely from USB power. However, if I disconnect the battery the unit doesn't boot. Failing that, I'd like to be able to disable the charger, or tell the CHIP / AXP209 to draw as much power as it needs.

Eventually, I found my way to wiki pages about [Power](http://www.chip-community.org/index.php/Power) on the CHIP and the [AXP209](http://www.chip-community.org/index.php/AXP209), and the [datasheet](https://linux-sunxi.org/images/8/89/AXP209_Datasheet_v1.0en.pdf) for the AXP209. I can see two promising commands in the datasheet which can be set by manipulating registers over i2c:

Page 18:

`If  the  system  just  utilizes  the  USB  for  power  supply  rather  than  communication,  or  the  USB  poweradapter is utilized, AXP209 can be set to “VBUS Direct Mode” by modifying register REG30H[6]`

(if the CHIP really is suddenly unable to draw enough power from USB)

Page 19:

`The  default  state  of  the  charger  is  “Enabled”.  (It  can  be  programmed  via  registers.  Refer  to  register REG33H.)`

(seems to be the closest thing to 'don't use the battery at all')

I can see these `i2cset` commands [listed in the CHIP wiki](http://www.chip-community.org/index.php/Power#AXP209_Current_Limit_Settings):

```
# Set to 900mA
i2cset -y -f 0 0x34 0x30 0x60

# Set to 500mA
i2cset -y -f 0 0x34 0x30 0x61

# Set to 100mA
i2cset -y -f 0 0x34 0x30 0x62

# Set to no limit
i2cset -y -f 0 0x34 0x30 0x63

# Show current value
i2cget -y -f 0 0x34 0x30
```

and I understand that these are setting values in `REG30H` (0x30) on the AXP209. However, I don't understand enough about registers and bitbashing to interpret the bit values in tables `10.11` and `10.14` on pages 33 & 34 of the [AXP209 datasheet](https://linux-sunxi.org/images/8/89/AXP209_Datasheet_v1.0en.pdf) into `i2cset` commands I can use on the CHIP. I'm a pretty decent programmer, but in fairly high-level languages like Python. Low-level stuff like this is alien to me.

So, my core question: what values do I need to set in `REG30H[6]` or `REG33H` on the AXP209, and what are the correct `i2cset` commands I can run on the CHIP to do that?

---

EDIT: `i2cget -y -f 0 0x34 0x30` returns `0x60` just after booting, which indicates that the device is set to draw 900mA by default.

Comment: Are you sure the I2C bus is working? What is the response of i2cdetect -y 0

Comment: @MarkoBuršič eh, can't preserve the formatting in a comment, but:
`
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
`

Comment: Address 0x34 is claimed by a kernel driver. That's what UU means. You have to unload that one before you can tweak the settings through userspace tools. (You could also un-attach 0x34 from the driver, but unloading the module is usually simpler. If you want to do it anyways, https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices , Method 4)

Comment: Like Janka said, the address 0x34 is being used by OS, probably by a device driver.You could probably control this IC via dedicated driver, see: https://forum.armbian.com/topic/10834-axp209-proper-driver/